# How max_docs and doc_frequency calculated in elastic search TDF

Tags: search, elasticsearch

Totally we have 6 documents and in that we have text 'fox' in 3 document. When we search using.

```
GET /my_index1/doc/_search?explain
{   "query": {  "term": {   "text": "fox"   }   }   }
```

Please find the explanation below

```
 {
    "text": "fox",
    "value": 1,
    "description": "idf(docFreq=1, maxDocs=2)",
    "details": []
 }
```

How th maxDocs is calculated. Since i have 6 documents in that 3 document has value fox. But why maxDocs displays 2 ? and also how the docFrequency is calculated ?

edited document

PUT /my_index1/doc/1
{ "text" : "fox" }

PUT /my_index1/doc/2
{ "text" : "fox" }

PUT /my_index1/doc/3
{ "text" : "document contain the fox trem to analyse the values" }

PUT /my_index1/doc/4
{ "text" : "hello" }

PUT /my_index1/doc/5
{ "text" : " this the the document  trem to analyse the values" }

PUT /my_index1/doc/6
{ "text" : " this the the document  trem to analyse the values" }

Comment: Provide those 6 documents.

Comment: PUT /my_index1/doc/1
{ "text" : "fox" }


PUT /my_index1/doc/3
{ "text" : "fox" }



PUT /my_index1/doc/3
{ "text" : "document contain the fox trem to analyse the values" }

PUT /my_index1/doc/4
{ "text" : "hello" }



PUT /my_index1/doc/5
{ "text" : " this the the document  trem to analyse the values" }

PUT /my_index1/doc/6
{ "text" : " this the the document  trem to analyse the values" }

Comment: You have two documents containing `fox` because you overrode document with ID 3: `PUT /my_index1/doc/3 { "text" : "fox" } PUT /my_index1/doc/3 { "text" : "document contain the fox trem to analyse the values" }` ;-)

Comment: @ Andrei Stefan edited the documents containing text